# Read at least n bytes from a named pipe in C

Tags: c, macos, named-pipes, fread

I have a multithreaded (pthread) C application running on macos where I'm trying to read from a named pipe with very low latency. There is a lot of data written to the pipe (tens of MB per second), and macos only has a few tens of KB worth of pipe buffer, so it's important I keep the pipe clean.

However, I can't afford to keep a whole core busy repeating the `read()` operation, as I would like to use that CPU for other operations.

I've tried waiting on `poll()` for a write on the named pipe, to then `read()` only on `POLLIN` events. This works, as I went from the cycle running many million times per second down to just a million times a second. However it's still a gigantic waste, as every `read()` operation only unloads an average of 10-20 bytes from the pipe.

I could `usleep()` in between reads, but I don't like this idea (and I tried it, I somehow can't get it to work reliably).

I believe `fread()` implements a buffer (and you can ask it to block and only return when at least n bytes are ready to be copied), but somehow I can only get it to work (to wait) with (for a) small number of bytes, say 4 bytes, not 16 or 128.

Comment: `(tens of MB per second),` is not a lot of data. I/O bandwidth could be in the range of 500MB/s `with very low latency.` : You cannot have both.

Comment: It's in the order of 10 MB per second. While I agree it's not a lot of data, you need to unload the pipe at least every ~6ms considering a perfectly uniform data stream (if the pipe buffer is 65k). My usleep implementation somehow crashes just above 800 nanoseconds, that I believe might have something to do with the implementation of usleep (or the scheduler deciding to schedule something taking a long time in between).

Comment: `However, I can't afford to keep a whole core busy repeating the read()` Blocking on I/O can be your friend.

Comment: I'm doing blocking I/O, but every single time I call my blocking read operation (with poll before it, too), I only retrieve a few bytes worth of data. I believe I explained that in the original question.

Comment: The solution is flow control, i.e. the process writing into the pipe needs to be more intelligent about how much data it puts into the pipe.

Comment: I would really rather not hack an external program, even if I too was assuming there really wasn't another way.

Comment: *However, I can't afford to keep a whole core busy repeating the `read()` operation, as I would like to use that CPU for other operations.*  Why not?  Why don't you price out the marginal cost for one more CPU and compare it to the cost of the time you're spending developing more complex code to "fix" something that's not a problem? And then the cost of keeping that code working in the future? You're using 100% of a CPU?  So what. That's what it's **FOR**.

Comment: You can't require a lower-bound on the amount of data that will be read; the system is always capable of returning less than you could accept.  You could write a function that achieves the result by looping until it has read enough to satisfy you, but that doesn't affect the system calls.  If the data is being written in small batches (a few tens of bytes), then you will in general only get a few tens of bytes from a read.  Sometimes you may get a couple of batches in a single read, but that's about it.  Presumably you are using blocking I/O on the pipe?

Comment: You mention "my implementation of `usleep`" — macOS provides `usleep()`, so what are you doing implementing it?  And since 800 nanoseconds is less than 1 microsecond, you can't wait the little with `usleep()`.  Maybe you need to show your code so we can see whether there's something non-obvious that's wrong — an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: I have a program `fifosize`, the source for which is available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository as file `fifosize.c` in the
[src/so-1936-1241](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-1936-1241) sub-directory.  That tells me that the macOS FIFO buffer size is 8192 (contrasted with 65536 for an anonymous pipe — see `pipesize.c` in the same directory).  I'm not sure that's a factor in your problem, beyond being an upper bound on how much data you'd be able to read from a FIFO in a single `read` operation.

Comment: By "my implementation of `usleep`" I meant my version of my program using `usleep`, sorry. @Jonathan, Thank you. That explains why I can only sleep around 800 microseconds instead of ~6ms before beginning dropping data (yes, I wanted to write micro instead of nano too, I was tired past midnight).